# How to handle page close in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to do something when user closes the page from "browser close". Is there a way to handle that event in server side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a window unload handler that does some AJAX to the server.  I don't know how reliable it would be in practice, though.

Comment: There are certainly lots of issues with this. @Yapiskan an alternative might be to look into Page_Unload or Session_End instead (depending on your exact requirements). Bear in mind Session_End only fires when using in proc session state.

Comment: And Page_Unload occurs for each page call. Session_End is not suitable in my case. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can try handling the javascript [OnUnload Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onunload.asp) and call the the [__dopostback() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720099(vs.71).aspx) for client script postback.

To clarify for the comments, it's not a foolproof pattern by any means, but maybe helpful depending on what the programmer is trying to do exactly.  Even if the postbacks are checked and filtered on the server-side, it would need to be an action that does not have to run *only once* and *always*.

Comment: Be very careful with this. In some (maybe all) browsers this event fires on refresh or moving to a different page, as well as when the browser is closed!

Comment: In fact if you look at the MSDN documents it can be fired for even more reasons that I have stated- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You also have to be careful what you use this event for. Do you need it to fire if the user kills the browser through Task Manager? Do you need it to fire when he logs off?

I think that, in most browsers, it will not fire in either of those two cases.